# Round to .5 or 1.0 in SQL

Tags: sql, t-sql, numbers, decimal, rounding

I'm looking to round values like

> 2.3913 -> 2.5
>
> 4.6667 -> 4.5
>
> 2.11 -> 2

How can I manage this in SQL?

Thanks

Comment: the first solution isnt settle with later 2 ones.

Comment: I don't understand how this is rounding. To the nearest half? Why does 2.11 get rounded down to 2, but 4.6667 gets rounded up to 5 instead of down to 4.5?

Comment: If it's "round to the nearest 0.5", then the second example should round to `4.5`, not `5`. If it's "round up to a 0.5", then the 3rd example should be `2.5`. Please write a rule we can actually follow.

Comment: Sorry I made a typo there, it was meant to round down to 4.5

Answer (score 69, accepted):

```
SELECT ROUND(2.2 * 2, 0) / 2
```

gets you to the nearest .5

Comment: This could have been written as `SELECT ROUND(2.2 / .5,0) * .5`.

Comment: Put a space between comma and zero. I thought it was a number (2.0), not the second parameter of ROUND function.

Comment: @DiegoQueiroz sure

Answer (score 7):

`round(round(column/5,1)*5,1)` closest 0.5 
`round(round(column/5,2)*5,2)`  closest 0.05