# how to round of decimal digit to nearest 50

Tags: sql-server-2008

How can it convert or round off the decimal digit to nearest 50. for e.g if i get 2.00 to 2.49  then it may change to 2.50 , 
2.50 to 2.99 then it may change to 3.00.
pls solve if anyone knows.

Comment: Duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9873990/round-to-5-or-1-0-in-sql

Comment: "nearest 50" would be 2.00-2.24 going to 2.00, 2.25 - 2.74 going to 2.50 and 2.75-2.99 going to 3.00 (with perhaps a little arguing over the precise boundaries). You're asking for "away from zero" or "rounding up".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know if this is an efficient way or not but I tried this :

```
IF OBJECT_ID('MyTable','U') IS NOT NULL 
    DROP TABLE MyTable
GO
CREATE TABLE MyTable (num DECIMAL(10,2))
GO
INSERT INTO MyTable 
values (1.00),(1.01),(1.49),(1.50),(1.51),(1.99),(2.00),
(11.00),(11.01),(11.49),(11.50),(11.51),(11.99),(12.00)

SELECT [num],
       CASE
         WHEN ( [num] - [Nbr] ) BETWEEN 0.01 AND 0.49 THEN [Nbr] + 0.5
         ELSE [Nbr]
       END AS [Result]
FROM   (SELECT [num],
               ROUND(num, 0) AS [Nbr]
        FROM   MyTable) t
```

Note:  Case when condition can be modified as per requirement.

Answer (score 2):

Something like this should produce your required rounding up:

```
SELECT CEILING(<input> * 2.0) / 2.0
```

Where `<input>` is the column or expression that's currently producing the values you want to round.

Comment: thanks, its working but slighltly to know about 123.00 , it is going to 123.0000